# My code detects Key Presses in Java but does detect when the key is lifted in StdDraw?

Tags: java, stdout, stdin, stddraw

So my project requires me to only use StdIn, StdOut and StdDraw. I have got code to detect when certain keys are pressed but it doesn't stop moving until the boundary is hit. I need it to only move 1 space but it moves across the entire the board and I cant figure out why???

I'm not allowed to use JFrame, ActionListener or anything besides StdIn, StdOut and StdDraw.

```
if (GUIenabled)
                    {
                        if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(81)) //Check if Q key is pressed
                        {
                            StdOut.println("Termination: User terminated game!");
                            EndGame(moveCounter, m, moveCounterScore);
                        }
                        
                        if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(87)) //Check if W key is pressed
                        {
                            if (rowSelect == 0)
                            {
                                rowSelect = 0;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                rowSelect--;
                                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.ORANGE);
                                StdDraw.filledSquare(columnSelect + 0.5, m - rowSelect + 1.5, 0.2);
                            }
                        }
                      
                        if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(83)) //Check if S key is pressed
                        {
                            if (rowSelect == m)
                            {
                                rowSelect = m;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                rowSelect++;
                                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.ORANGE);
                                StdDraw.filledSquare(columnSelect + 0.5, m - rowSelect + 1.5, 0.2);
                            }
                        }
              
                        if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(65)) //Check if A key is pressed
                        {
                            if (columnSelect == 0)
                            {
                                columnSelect = 0;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                columnSelect--;
                                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.ORANGE);
                                StdDraw.filledSquare(columnSelect + 0.5, m - rowSelect + 1.5, 0.2);
                            }
                        }
              
                        if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(68)) //Check if D key is pressed
                        {
                            if (columnSelect == m)
                            {
                                columnSelect = m;
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                columnSelect++;
                                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.ORANGE);
                                StdDraw.filledSquare(columnSelect + 0.5, m - rowSelect + 1.5, 0.2);
                            }
                        }
}
```

If there is anyone that can shed light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the weird indentation, idk what happened

Comment: I think we might need to see more of your code to know what's going on.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the point of code like this:

`if (columnSelect == 0)   {  columnSelect = 0;   }     else    { ... `

Why not just have `if (columnSelect != 0) { ... ` ?